# Efficient way of Element lookup in a Python List?

Tags: python, arrays, list, lookup, traversal

I have a list of files in a directory. I have to process only certain files from that directory. filelist is my desired file-list. How do I go about achieving this? Not interested in a bash solution since I have to do it all in this one Python script. Thanks much!

```
for record in result:
    filelist.append(record[0])

print filelist


for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1].strip() + "/"):
    for file in filelist: #This doesn't work, how else do I do this? If file equals to my desired file-list, then do something.
        print file
```

Sorry guys, not sure how I missed this! Early morning coding I guess!! Mods, please close it unless someone wants to chip in with an efficient way of doing it.

```
for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1].strip() + "/"):
    if file in filelist:
        print file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order and uniqueness don't matter, you can use a `set` intersection, which will be much more efficient.

```
import set
os_list = os.listdir(sys.argv[1].strip() + "/")
for file in set(os_list) & set(filelist):
    #...
```

Example of improvement:

```
import random
import timeit

l = [random.randint(1,10000) for i in range(1000)]
l2 = [random.randint(1,10000) for i in range(1000)]

def f1():
    l3 = []
    for i in l:
        if i in l2:
            l3.append(i)
    return l3

def f2():
    l3 = []
    for i in set(l) & set(l2):
        l3.append(i)
    return l3

t1 = timeit.Timer('f1()', 'from __main__ import f1')
print t1.timeit(100) #2.0850549985

t2 = timeit.Timer('f2()', 'from __main__ import f2')
print t2.timeit(100) #0.0162533142857
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when you're dealing with an I/O device (like a hard drive), the performance differences in your code will be dwarfed by the time it takes to do the I/O operations.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to do a test:

```
for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1].strip() + "/"):
    if file in filelist:
        # Found a file in the wanted-list.
        print file
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to do something like this:

```
for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1].strip() + "/"): 
    if file in filelist:
        print file
```

Note that I just changed the second `for` to an `if`. However, since you were asking about efficiency, you probably want to change `filelist` from being a `list` to being a `set` or a `dict` to make the `in` operator more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
print [x for x in os.listdir(sys.argv[1].strip() + "/") if x in filelist]
```